# Why isn't container filling the whole screen?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set a black background for one of my React Routes.  But when the page is rendered, it seems like the container I set the black background to isn't covering the whole screen.  Even if I set the background in the div in my App.js to black, the container doesn't fully cover the screen.  I included an shortened version of my code below.

foo.js Route

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const StyledContainer = withStyles({
    root: {
        background: 'black',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
    }
  })(Container);



export default function Foo(){
    return(
        <StyledContainer>
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={0}
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                justify="center"
                style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
            >
                Hello World
            </Grid>
        </StyledContainer>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Foo from './routes/Foo';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact to path="/foo">
            <Foo />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a css file you import on index / App containing your global styling (similar to what you would get by creating a new react app through `npx create-react-app app-name`.

In there, you need to have the following styles to avoid default margin / borders:

```js
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
};
```